# Accessing current google navigation status

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I would like to create a drivers screen where some useful information are displayed. I want to display navigation hints, but I don't want to program a whole navigation system. 
Is there a way to access the current navigation hints from google navigation or any other free navigation app?

I prefer access to an android app, because I thought the easiest prototype would be an android app. But I'm thankfull for any information about it and how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if your use case is compatible with restrictions exposed in the Terms of Service of Google Maps API. Have a look at section 10.4.c (iii)

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

Comment: thanks, you're right. Seems like that does not fit in to googles policy. 
But Google was just my first intention. I'm not bound to google. 
I would also use any other service, even though google would have been nice because of its many users.